# array slicing in php

Tags: php, arrays

I've below array:-

```
Array
(
    [adate] => 
    [ip_address] => 
    [atime] => 
    [self_fname] => hjhbhj
    [self_mi_nm] => bjb
    [self_last_nm] => bb
    [self_preferred_nm] => bbjhb
    [patient_is1] => 1
    [party_fname] => tgn
    [party_mname] => 
    [party_lname] => gn
    [party_str1] => 
    [party_apt1] => 
    [party_city1] => 
    [pt_str1] => 
    [pt_apt1] => 
    [pt_city1] => 
    [pt_state1] => 
    [pt_zip1] => 
)
```

I want to divide this array into 2 array with **"party_"** and **"pt_"**. The output will be like below:-

```
Array
(
    [party_fname] => tgn
    [party_mname] => 
    [party_lname] => gn
    [party_str1] => 
    [party_apt1] => 
    [party_city1] =>  
)

Array
( 
    [pt_str1] => 
    [pt_apt1] => 
    [pt_city1] => 
    [pt_state1] => 
    [pt_zip1] => 
)
```

Does anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: You really can't think of any way to do this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'll give you a tip; Iterate over the elements and use string matching.

Comment: The most basic way of doing this would be to loop through the array as a key=>value combo, check the key name for starting with what you want, and add to a new array variable; one for the party keys, on for the pt keys

Comment: @JohnConde yes - I've an idea to use array_slice() and array_search() function in combine. It'll give me proper output. But the above is an example array. actual array is containing more that 200 element. and I need to make 9 arrays. That's why I was searching for easy and better solution than mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use foreach and strpos to get the results you want.

```
$arr = ORIGINAL DATA;
$arr1 = $arr2 = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
   if(strpos($key, 'party_') === 0){
       $arr1[$key] = $value;
       }
   else if(strpos($key, 'pt_') === 0){
       $arr2[$key] = $value;
       }
   }
```

This will output two arrays, with arr1 having all the data with keys that start with 'party_' and arr2 having all the keys that start with 'pt_'.

Comment: I'd recommend a `preg_match` over `strpos` to make sure the pattern is at the start of the string.

Comment: strpos is right here, because he sad `=== 0`

Comment: @lolka_bolka Oh, gotcha +1

Answer (score 0):

Read this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

if you call your original array as `$arrayMain`, Code would be:

```
$arrayParty = array_slice($arrayMain, 8, 6, true);
```

and

```
$arrayPt = array_slice($arrayMain, 14, 5, true);
```